# Using gluortho2d but drawing functions don't use new coordinates

Tags: opengl, 2d, coordinates, orthographic

I have a setup function that sets up the viewport to take up the full window size, load the identity matrix, and then uses `gluOrtho2d()` to set up a a coordinate system within that viewport. If my understanding of this function is correct, I should now be able to call my drawing functions using coordinates from 0 to 780 on the x-axis and 0 to 460 on the y-axis

```
void gl_setup(void) {
  glViewport(0,0, 780,460);
  glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D(0,0,780,460);

  return ;
}
```

However, in my my_display function, my shapes are drawn according to a (-1,1,-1,1) coordinate system. for example,

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(0, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(0, 1.0f);
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0);
glEnd();
```

draws two lines, one directly down the middle of the viewport from top to bottom, and one directly across the middle of the viewport from left to right. In the coordinate system I thought I defined above, should I not have used

```
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(0, 230.0f);
glVertex2f(780, 230.0f);
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
glVertex2f(390.0f, 0);
glVertex2f(390.0f, 460.0f);
glEnd();
```

or thereabouts?

EDIT: the drawing happens in the `my_display()` function, which is the `glutDisplayFunc` callback. That function looks like this:

```
void my_display(void) {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;

  glColor3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.79);

  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  glVertex2f(0, -1.0f);
  glVertex2f(0, 1.0f);
  glEnd();
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0);
  glVertex2f(1.0f, 0);
  glEnd();

  glColor3f(1.0f, 0, 0);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -1.0f);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -2.0f);
  glEnd();
  glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
  glVertex2f(-2.0f, 0);
  glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0);
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();

  return ;
}
```

EDIT 2: My main function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  glutInit( &argc, argv ) ;
  glut_setup() ;  
  gl_setup() ;
  glutMainLoop() ;

  return(0) ;
}
```

I have glSetup above. `glut_setup()` is where I define all my callbacks:

```
 glutDisplayFunc( my_display );
 glutReshapeFunc( my_reshape ); 
 glutKeyboardFunc( my_keyboard );
 glutMouseFunc( my_mouse);
```

And `my_reshape` looks like the following, which to my understanding (which could admittedly be very far from the truth) keep the viewport the same size whenever the window is resized, and keep it relatively centered:

```
void my_reshape(int w, int h) {
  // update window dimensions
  WIN_W = w;
  WIN_H = h;

  int win_x = (w-780)/2;
  int win_y = (h-460)/2;

  glViewport (win_x,win_y,780,460);
  return;
}
```

Comment: A wild guess would be that you reset the projection matrix with some `glLoadIdentity()` call or similiar, as you leave the matrix mode at `GL_PROJECTION`. But with the code given so far, this is far from certain.

Comment: You're right @derhass, I have added the full function that actually does the drawing.

Comment: That is still not enough. Where do you call `gl_setup()`, and what happens inbetween that and entering the main loop? Also other callbacks might interfere here, like a reshape function.

Comment: I've added my main function so you can see where `gl_setup` is called, the callbacks I've added, and my reshape callback. If you need any more info I will gladly try and provide it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters to gluOrtho2D are in the wrong order. It should be left, right, bottom, top which would make the correct order for your program gluOrtho2D(0,780,0,460). The way you defined it would have a width of 0 which most likely results in an error that doesn't set the projection matrix leaving it at the default. See the function specification here: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml.